# Getting error in EJB example

Tags: java, ejb

I am trying to Implement an EJB example from [this URL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ejb/ejb_create_application.htm)

But EJBTester.java at client side giving an error that is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: jndi.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at com.tutorialspoint.test.EJBTester.<init>(EJBTester.java:23)
    at com.tutorialspoint.test.EJBTester.main(EJBTester.java:37)
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:674)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at com.tutorialspoint.test.EJBTester.<init>(EJBTester.java:28)
    at com.tutorialspoint.test.EJBTester.main(EJBTester.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:72)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:61)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:671)
    ... 5 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tutorialspoint.test.EJBTester.testStatelessEjb(EJBTester.java:51)
null
    at com.tutorialspoint.test.EJBTester.main(EJBTester.java:39)
```

Could you please provide me a good example from which I can clear my EJB concept?

Comment: Can you show some code + structure of what you have. Are you loading the `jndi.properties` explicitly or do you have it on your classpath?

Comment: I am adding jndi.properties explicitly. In src folder. where I am making packing "com.tutorialspoint.test" for class EJBTester

Comment: Are you loading the `jndi.properties` explicitly?

Comment: i am making jndi.properties file in src folder.

Comment: And how are you instantiating the `InitialContextFactory`?

Comment: import javax.naming.InitialContext;  BufferedReader brConsoleReader = null; 
   Properties props = new Properties();;
   InitialContext ctx;
   {
    
    
       try {
      props.load(new FileInputStream("jndi.properties"));
      } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      try {
      ctx = new InitialContext(props);            
      } catch (NamingException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      brConsoleReader = 
      new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   }

Comment: import javax.naming.InitialContext;     Help me I so confused.

Comment: Could you please check this Ur : "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ejb/ejb_create_application.htm"l at last i copied this Code

Comment: did you have a look at my answer?

Comment: Yes thank you its work

Comment: Please mark as answered http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 1):

Your code  (from the comments)

```
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
BufferedReader brConsoleReader = null;
Properties props = new Properties();

InitialContext ctx;
{
    try {
        props.load(new FileInputStream("jndi.properties"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext(props);
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    brConsoleReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Will try to load the `jndi.properties` from the working directory

Just do the following:

```
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
```

This loads the `jndi.properties`  from the root of your classpath as a resource.

If you really wanted the load the `jndi.properties` explicitly (from the classpath) use the following

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream input = loader.getResourceAsStream("jndi.properties");
if (input == null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find jndi.properties in class path");
}
props.load(input);
```

Comment: Thank You, It's Work. Thank You ver Much